# python streaming with hadoop is not working

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming

I'm trying to run hadoop streaming map-reduce job using python.
i keep getting this error message with no idea how to fix it.

this is the command I'm using.

```
hdfs -jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.jar -input /input/ -output /out22 -mapper "python /mapper.py" -file /mapper.py -file /reducer.py -reducer "python /reducer.py"
```

and here is the error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

is there anything wrong with what I'm doing ? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command which you are trying is wrong, you should use hadoop command as follows.

> **hadoop jar** /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.jar
>   -input /input/ -output /out22 -mapper "python /mapper.py" -file /mapper.py -file /reducer.py -reducer "python /reducer.py

hdfs command is used for HDFS(Hadoop file system) related operations, where as hadoop is common utility which can be used for mapreduce as well as hdfs operation.

Instead of using hadoop command, you may use `mapred jar` or `yarn jar` command also, depends on the mapreduce framework(classic or yarn) your are having